# Powershell - named parameters and script built-in functions?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a script, that accepts named arguments - but the script also has functions in it... This gives me a problem, that I cannot see how to fix.
The script - c:\temp\example.ps1 - looks like:

```
function test
{
 param($p1)
 write-host $p1
}

param(
 [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
 [switch]$EnableOption,
 [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
 [string]$Hostname
)

test -p1 $Hostname
```

This gives me:

```
param : The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Temp\example.ps1:7 char:1
+ param(
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (param:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How do I fix this - so that named parameters can be used for functions - but also be used in the "main" script (getting the command line arguments when calling the script) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order in your script

```
param(
 [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
 [switch]$EnableOption,
 [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
 [string]$Hostname
)

function test
{
 param($p1)
 write-host $p1
}


test -p1 $Hostname
```

`Param` section must be at the start of your code